# Animating while navigating between two activities

Tags: android, animation

I want to show an animation when the user tries to navigate between one activity to the other .How can i achieve this?

Upon googling i found that we can use styles and set animation using themes for an activity. But when i do so i am unable to see any kind of animation happening. Is it doable?

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2ac12ea2bfc50908?pli=1

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4409

Can any one help me plz..

Comment: Your "its urgent" makes me avoid answering.

Comment: i have removed it now...can you please reply ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aiming at android 2.0 and greater then you can use overridePendingTransition(). There is a good [anddev tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/splash-fade-activity-animations-overridependingtransition-t9464.html) for it.

Comment: thanks for the reply...is it possible to do it for 1.5 SDK and above?...This method has been introduced only in 2.0 SDK as u said...

Comment: not using this method. There may be another way, but I am not aware of it. You could probably use an activity holder such as TabHost or something.